# Which gradle version to use with the latest Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Could not find a definite resource as of which gradle, gradleplugin versions to use with a specific / latest  AndroidStudio version.

**UPDATE:**
Best official resource answering the question: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

Comment: Official documentation may help you: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html I'm assuming you're using Android Studio 1.3, right?

Comment: http://services.gradle.org/distributions

Comment: Plugin 1.3.1 and gradle 2.4/2.5

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla please make this an answer, and I will mark it as the accepted one. Other documentation links specify 1.1.0 which is not the latest android plugin for gradle

Comment: @Guy post it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official documentation is what you need: https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html

**UPDATE JANUARY 2017**

Android Studio 2.2.3

```
Gradle 2.2.3 or higher.
Build Tools 25.0.2 or higher.
```

Using Android Studio 1.3 with this dependencies:

```
Gradle 2.2.1 or higher.
Build Tools 21.1.1 or higher.
```

Also, Gradle 2.7 was release 14th September 2015: http://gradle.org/

Answer (score 3):

This would be more of a comment but I haven't accumulated enough points as of yet.
If you've updated your Android Studio to 1.3.2 version then I would suggest using Build Tools Version 23.0.0 and compile API 23 Android 6.0.

In your top level gradle file;

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "your.package.name"
      minSdkVersion 15 // min sdk can be any sdk you want to target
      targetSdkVersion 23 // target compiled version
   }
}
```

As for Gradle Version - 2.4 or higher up to latest 2.7.

[image]

In your App gradle file;

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```